# Other usages of "of"

Tags: meaning, prepositions

> A real palace of a house
>
> That idiot of a doctor

Would you show me the phrases above in some other ways that mean the same thing?

Any comment would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether this type of sentence is an example of inversion or if instead we're choosing examples from a larger category.  In each case the meaning is simply that the object is the subject.  "The house is a palace." or "The doctor is an idiot."  It's a fairly common usage in conversation.

Comment: Thanks. But, what about meaning? is there any difference?

Comment: What did you think your examples mean?  Was it different than the phrasings Jason Patterson offered?

Comment: I have no idea as I really have never seen such a constuction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The phrasing used in your examples might be construed as more emphatic than "That doctor is an idiot." (but not as emphatic as "Tthat doctor is an idiot!") — any of these can be considered hyperbole.

Likewise in the house/palace example, the house is not literally a palace; is is LIKE a palace, so the phrasing is understood as a metaphor (exaggerated) rather than a true equivalence.

Also, the "X of a Y" construction lets you create such sentences as "That idiot of a doctor told me that LDL was "bad cholesterol".  Which is shorter than "That doctor is [such] an idiot. He told me that LDL was "bad cholesterol".

Comment: So, which one would be correct? they are idiot doctors. they are idiotic doctors.

Comment: @nima **idiot** is a noun, and can't modify a noun as an adjective. so **They are idiot doctors** is actually not correct. One might use it like this **They are idiot-doctors**, but that is not common. On the other hand **idiotic doctor** is okay.